# In Mongo how do I rename a new added field in an aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

When doing an aggregation I add a new field that has data from another object but in the last step I want to rename the field to something else(the original object I am getting data from)

What operator can I use to do that, of course, $replace doesn't work in this case

```
{
    $match: { _id: id },
},
{
    $addFields: {
        'userMetadata.active': '$user.active',
        'userMetadata.metadata': '$user.metadata',
    },
},
{ $unset: 'user' }
//Here I want to replace userMetadata with user
```

Thank you

Basically, I am looking for an alternative to adding this

```
{
    $addFields: {
       user: '$userMetadata',
    },
},
{ $unset: 'userMetadata' },
```

This solution works but I am not sure how performant it is over long lists

Update 2:
This seems to work, still more stages than I want

```
{
    $addFields: {
        'userMeta.active': '$user.active',
        'userMeta.metadata.name': '$user.metadata.name',
        'userMeta.metadata.url': '$user.metadata.url',
        user: '$$REMOVE',
    },
},
{
    $addFields: {
        user: '$userMeta',
        userMeta: '$$REMOVE',
    },
},
```

Comment: Set `user` field with `userMetadata`, then unset `userMetadata` field? `{ $set: "$userMetadata"}, { "$unset": "$userMetadata" }`

Comment: But based on your current pipeline and requirement, it is quite odd that you set the existing field to new field, and rename new field to old field. Why not just use back the existing field and set the desired value to it?

Comment: @YongShun the object is too complicated and deep and I would end up with 50 unsets

Comment: Would be great if you can provide a sample input and output document for reference. Thanks.

Comment: Added details, I am looking for a simple way of replacing: addFields unset addFields unset stages with one stage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
{
    $addFields: {
        'user': '$userMetadata',
        'userMetadata': '$$REMOVE'
    }
}
```

`$unset` also accepts an array:

```
{ $unset: [ 'user', '<more fields>', ... ] }
```

Or use `$project`, it removes all (apart from `_id`) fields which are not listed:

```
{
    $project: {
        'user': '$userMetadata',
        '_id': 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Using $$REMOVE seems to work, down to 2 stages, thx